# Caliburn.Micro HelloScreens sample build error

Tags: silverlight, caliburn.micro

Getting this error when I try to build the Caliburn.Micro sample project "Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens" from http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com

Error: The type 'TDocument' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Caliburn.Micro.Conductor'

TDocument is defined in the the class DocumentWorkspace  as

```
public abstract class DocumentWorkspace<TDocument> : Conductor<TDocument>.Collection.OneActive, IDocumentWorkspace where TDocument : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDeactivate, IHaveDisplayName 
{
```

Comment: This is now fixed in the latest updates to the sample at codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

the **class** keyword is missing from the abstraction to tell the DocumentWorkspace that the TDocument was a derived object class. Try

```
public abstract class DocumentWorkspace<TDocument> : Conductor<TDocument>.Collection.OneActive, IDocumentWorkspace where TDocument : class, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDeactivate, IHaveDisplayName { }
```